# Creating new object/table, correct format?

Tags: powershell, scripting

```
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#First uri is to pull a list of subusers
$uri = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers"

$uri2 = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/teammates?limit=500&offset=0"
#Prompts for target email address
$email = Read-Host "Enter the users email"

$headers1 = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token"}

#Get a list of all subusers
$subs = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -uri $uri -headers $headers1
$subuser = $subs | select-object username

#Loop through all subusers, displaying usernames
foreach ($su in $subuser){
    $headers2 = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token" 
     "on-behalf-of" = $su.username
}
   $teamarray = invoke-restmethod -method get -uri $uri2 -headers $headers2
   #$teamarray.gettype()
   
   #$teamarray.result | select-object username 
}

#[pscustomobject]@{
 #   Subuser = $subuser
  #  TeamMate = $teamarray
   # }

$objSubuserTMTable = [ordered]@{
    SubUser = $subuser;
    Username = $teamarray
    }

new-object PSObject -property $objSubuserTMTable | format-table
```

So this part of my script produces a table, except it's not. I get 1 truncated line formed of both columns. Whats the correct syntax to properly format this as a two column table?

Thanks!

Comment: You created 1 object, so a table with exactly 1 row is what you should expect.

Comment: So.. are you saying a table should contain multiple objects if you want it to have multiple columns?

Comment: Yes! Is `$teamarray` an array of user names? If so, you'll want to create 1 object _per username_

Comment: Oh geez.. yeah it is an array but one that can vary in length. I certainly don't want to create an object per...  There's got to be some way.

Comment: Why not? You don't need to know the count up front - `foreach($username in $teamarray){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you would like this formatted, but you can join all TeamArray usernames together like below (I'm using the semi-colon):

```
$objSubuserTMTable = foreach ($su in $subuser){
    $headers2 = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $token" 
        "on-behalf-of" = $su.username
    }
    $teamarray = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri2 -Headers $headers2
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        SubUser  = $su.username
        Username = ($teamarray.result | Select-Object -ExpandProperty username) -join '; '
    }
}


# output on screen. Will truncate if this exceeds the with of the console
$objSubuserTMTable | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file you can open in Excel (not truncated)
$objSubuserTMTable | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\TeamUsersFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as written. I ran the below on my system and got expected output. Your problem must lie elsewhere.

```
$subuser = "subuser"
$teamarray = "username"

$objSubuserTMTable = [ordered]@{
    SubUser = $subuser;
    Username = $teamarray
    }

new-object PSObject -property $objSubuserTMTable | format-table
```

Output:

```
SubUser Username
------- --------
subuser username
```

Comment: Interesting... I edited my post to include all of the script. Still can't figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple rows you have to have multiple rows of data.  Format table works on sets where each object represents a row

```
$objSubuserTMTable = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SubUser = 'subuser1'
        Username = 'teamarray1'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SubUser = 'subuser2'
        Username = 'teamarray2'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SubUser = 'subuser3'
        Username = 'teamarray3'
    }
)
$objSubuserTMTable | format-table
```

Output:

```
SubUser  Username
-------  --------
subuser1 teamarray1
subuser2 teamarray2
subuser3 teamarray3
```